# Sinon / Chai - check throw to be instance of error on one line

Tags: unit-testing, chai, throw

I have the following test and it works:

```
expect(()=>{ throw new Error('foo')}).to.throw('foo');
```

I can also do:

```
expect(()=>{ throw new Error('foo')}).to.throw('foo').to.be.instanceOf(Error);
```

But is there a way to do this with one check, something like:

```
expect(()=>{ throw new Error('foo')}).to.throw(new Error('foo'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the same instance between throw and expected throw :

```
const error = new Error('foo');
expect(()=>{ throw error }).to.throw(error)
```

Comment: How is that possible if I'm testing another script exactly?

Comment: you could export the error instance but it's a bad idea! Why you don't want to use `expect(()=>{ throw new Error('foo')}).to.throw('foo').to.be.instanceOf(Error);` ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `throw` assertion with two arguments:

```
expect(() => { throw new Error('foo'); }).to.throw(Error, 'foo');
```

The first argument checks that the thrown instance is an instance of `Error` and the 2nd argument checks that its message is `"foo"`.

The usage above is documented [here](http://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw). You have to scroll down a bit to find the place where the usage with two arguments is described.

---

This code you show in your question cannot ever succeed:

```
expect(()=>{ throw new Error('foo')}).to.throw(new Error('foo'));
```

When you pass an `Error` instance to `throw`, the test can success only if the error thrown and the passed instance are the same object. The case above fails for the same reason that `new Error('foo') === new Error('foo')` is false. The object thrown and the object passed to `throw` cannot be the same instance. This succeeds:

```
const err = new Error('x');
expect(() => { throw err; }).to.throw(err);
```